# Add image to Excel (.xlsx) using NPOI C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I want to insert image to an XLSX file (not xls) using NPOI.
I am using `XSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFSheet`

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("SomeImage.jpg");
int picInd = workbook.AddPicture(data, XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
XSSFCreationHelper helper = workbook.GetCreationHelper() as XSSFCreationHelper;
XSSFDrawing drawing = _sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch() as XSSFDrawing;
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = helper.CreateClientAnchor() as XSSFClientAnchor;
anchor.Col1 = 1;
anchor.Row1 = 1;
XSSFPicture pict = drawing.CreatePicture(anchor, picInd) as XSSFPicture;
```

The file is saved successfully. but while opening it showing the following error and on clicking yes, it does not display the image.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just googling for "NPOI image Excel" or checking NPOI's documentation? There are a lot of duplicate questions already

Comment: Most of them are for xls file which is using HSSFWorkbook. I could not find any solution for XSSFWorkbook

Comment: this one is not answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086803/insert-image-to-excel-file-using-npoi

Comment: Not answered but shows at least an *attempt* to create the image. The API is there too. The NPOI repository on Codeplex has a *lot* of examples, including examples that show how to add a picture.

Comment: I already tried this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086803/insert-image-to-excel-file-using-npoi). applied some changes but did not work

Comment: *Which* one is "that one"? What did you try? What was the problem? How do you expect people to help if you don't provide *any* information?

Comment: If you want a ready-made answer, perhaps you should look for a more popular library like EPPlus. Googling for "EPPlus image" returns a lot of examples and articles on how to add pictures

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("someImage.png");
int pictureIndex = workbook.AddPicture(data, PictureType.PNG);
ICreationHelper helper = workbook.GetCreationHelper();
IDrawing drawing = _sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
IClientAnchor anchor = helper.CreateClientAnchor();
anchor.Col1 = 0;//0 index based column
anchor.Row1 = 0;//0 index based row
IPicture picture = drawing.CreatePicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
picture.Resize();
```

Comment: Excellent. You saved me some hours. Just an improvement for image not resize when columns size change: `anchor.AnchorType = AnchorType.MoveDontResize;`

Comment: Thank you, used NPOI before, but for text only. Works for me !