# Can we able to export html invoice content to excel or Csv file using jquery,javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one invoice page in my project that contains bar-code, shipping address details and items grid, my concern is can we able to export Html page Invoice content to Excel file or CSV File using Jquery, Javascript or asp.net MVC if anyone knows please let me know[image]

thanks
shiva

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to export the web page to excel instead of PDF?

You can use [NPOI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138848/add-image-to-excel-xlsx-using-npoi-c-sharp) in asp.net to create excel file and do it with your barcode image.

As for simply output PDF file, you can convert your html to PDF by [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Comment: we already doing html to PDF conversion by using kendo PDF export function but as per client requirement i need the excel export also

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery Plugin To Export Table Data To CSV File.
I hope this will solve your problem [jQuery plugin Link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Export-Table-Data-To-CSV-File-table2csv.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need what exactly shown in my image you sent only export table data to excel